# python Print String uppercase only

Tags: python, string, list

I'd like to get a string and print it by separating the lowercase character classification.

```
s = list()
s = input('input : ')
```

and i wanna recognize, and remove lowercase.

Comment: Show a sample input and output. Also share what you have done so far.

Comment: what does "separating the lowercase character classification" mean?

Comment: s is input sentence and if it has lowercase, it will be removed.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! You look like you are new here, if any of the answers below has helped, kindly accept the best one as an answer by checking the tick mark on the left. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the inbuilt string functions which inludes `.isupper` and `.islower` then join them accordingly if you want to.

```
inp = input()

up = ''.join(i for i in inp if i.isupper())
low = ''.join(i for i in inp if i.islower())

print('upper: {} \nlower:{} '.format(up,low))

BSDSsdsdSD
upper: BSDSSD 
lower:sdsd
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex like so:

```
import re
l = input('input :')
print(re.sub('[a-z]','',l))
```